# Connect to SQL Server 2005 from JAVA 8

Tags: sql-server-2005, java-8, connection

Am preparing some code for migrating from VB&SQL Server to our new solution based on JAVA&Oracle DB, so am trying to connect on the SQL Server to query some data and then to put them on our new oracle tables, but when I try to connect via this code:

```
DriverManager.registerDriver(new com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver());
Connexion con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.10.97:1433;databaseName=ArchiveCCE", "test", "test");
```

it keeps show me the following error :

```
déc. 31, 2018 3:04:14 PM com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection Prelogin AVERTISSEMENT: ConnectionID:1 ClientConnectionId: c199c628-c3c8-4850-8252-9446b6c90cab Prelogin error: host 192.168.10.97 port 1433 Unexpected end of prelogin response after 0 bytes read
déc. 31, 2018 3:04:14 PM com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection Prelogin AVERTISSEMENT: ConnectionID:1 ClientConnectionId: f468dbd4-f340-4e6a-a6ab-103350c3a547 Prelogin error: host 192.168.10.97 port 1433 Unexpected end of prelogin response after 0 bytes read
déc. 31, 2018 3:04:14 PM com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection Prelogin AVERTISSEMENT: ConnectionID:1 ClientConnectionId: 8c96557e-88a6-4745-a1c6-f839bfc44142 Prelogin error: host 192.168.10.97 port 1433 Unexpected end of prelogin response after 0 bytes read
déc. 31, 2018 3:04:15 PM com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection Prelogin AVERTISSEMENT: ConnectionID:1 ClientConnectionId: 2987d710-3007-47a9-bfaa-2573c79ef049 Prelogin error: host 192.168.10.97 port 1433 Unexpected end of prelogin response after 0 bytes read
déc. 31, 2018 3:04:15 PM com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection Prelogin AVERTISSEMENT: ConnectionID:1 ClientConnectionId: f5f84cb6-33ac-4dc7-a500-cdb957470d01 Prelogin error: host 192.168.10.97 port 1433 Unexpected end of prelogin response after 0 bytes read
déc. 31, 2018 3:04:16 PM com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection Prelogin AVERTISSEMENT: ConnectionID:1 ClientConnectionId: f7eaa8cc-0a65-455b-bc8d-df64b18f0532 Prelogin error: host 192.168.10.97 port 1433 Unexpected end of prelogin response after 0 bytes read
déc. 31, 2018 3:04:17 PM com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection Prelogin AVERTISSEMENT: ConnectionID:1 ClientConnectionId: a223c4aa-f1c6-47c4-b40c-1d39a5a03db0 Prelogin error: host 192.168.10.97 port 1433 Unexpected end of prelogin response after 0 bytes read
déc. 31, 2018 3:04:18 PM com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection Prelogin AVERTISSEMENT: ConnectionID:1 ClientConnectionId: d822a2b8-8387-43ba-a814-6dade9f71e5f Prelogin error: host 192.168.10.97 port 1433 Unexpected end of prelogin response after 0 bytes read
déc. 31, 2018 3:04:19 PM com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection Prelogin AVERTISSEMENT: ConnectionID:1 ClientConnectionId: d152a753-708b-4bcb-aa2e-87b5346911df Prelogin error: host 192.168.10.97 port 1433 Unexpected end of prelogin response after 0 bytes read
déc. 31, 2018 3:04:20 PM com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection Prelogin AVERTISSEMENT: ConnectionID:1 ClientConnectionId: 1dba43a1-e6e3-4dc7-9707-42ba909a30aa Prelogin error: host 192.168.10.97 port 1433 Unexpected end of prelogin response after 0 bytes read
déc. 31, 2018 3:04:21 PM com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection Prelogin AVERTISSEMENT: ConnectionID:1 ClientConnectionId: 193ee01c-f0b8-4e0c-8e06-77f4bde7ef5c Prelogin error: host 192.168.10.97 port 1433 Unexpected end of prelogin response after 0 bytes read
déc. 31, 2018 3:04:22 PM com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection Prelogin AVERTISSEMENT: ConnectionID:1 ClientConnectionId: 34a6c52e-bbad-44a5-a4c3-acb712bf7a2a Prelogin error: host 192.168.10.97 port 1433 Unexpected end of prelogin response after 0 bytes read
déc. 31, 2018 3:04:23 PM com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection Prelogin AVERTISSEMENT: ConnectionID:1 ClientConnectionId: 4bbfa516-99db-49bc-8648-657627b3010d Prelogin error: host 192.168.10.97 port 1433 Unexpected end of prelogin response after 0 bytes read
déc. 31, 2018 3:04:24 PM com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection Prelogin AVERTISSEMENT: ConnectionID:1 ClientConnectionId: ea3649d5-1adc-4dd4-a340-a2d0d95e8af3 Prelogin error: host 192.168.10.97 port 1433 Unexpected end of prelogin response after 0 bytes read
déc. 31, 2018 3:04:25 PM com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection Prelogin AVERTISSEMENT: ConnectionID:1 ClientConnectionId: ad4d76d7-77ca-4686-ab2a-3f802f36d533 Prelogin error: host 192.168.10.97 port 1433 Unexpected end of prelogin response after 0 bytes read
déc. 31, 2018 3:04:26 PM com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection Prelogin AVERTISSEMENT: ConnectionID:1 ClientConnectionId: bbaa643f-1b0c-4d92-b5ff-81efb1f09a83 Prelogin error: host 192.168.10.97 port 1433 Unexpected end of prelogin response after 0 bytes read
déc. 31, 2018 3:04:27 PM com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection Prelogin AVERTISSEMENT: ConnectionID:1 ClientConnectionId: dcbff2e2-1673-435e-b1a8-de5ea610fc77 Prelogin error: host 192.168.10.97 port 1433 Unexpected end of prelogin response after 0 bytes read
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Échec de la connexion TCP/IP à l'hôte 192.168.10.97, port 1433. Erreur : « Le pilote a reçu une réponse de préconnexion inattendue. Examinez les propriétés de connexion et vérifiez qu'une instance de SQL Server est en cours d'exécution sur l'hôte et accepte les connexions TCP/IP au port. Ce pilote peut être utilisé uniquement avec SQL Server 2005 ou ultérieur. ». ClientConnectionId:dcbff2e2-1673-435e-b1a8-de5ea610fc77
```

[SQL SERVER Test user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6uVl8.png)

I verified that the SQL Server TCP/IP is enabled, I verified the port number (1344), I verified the Authentication method (SQL authentication) I even created the user "test" PW: "test" by my self, don't know how to get the connection established !

Could some one help me please ?